# How to close iterm2 tabs using exit command?

Tags: iterm2

How to close the tab using exit command and don't show Broken Pipe?
How to set it?

[image: Broken Pipe]

Answer (score 1):

Session -> Edit session, Session tab, ensure 'Automatically close a session when it ends' is checked; and then, General tab, ensure Default profile is selected (or whichever profile you're wanting to set), and click 'Click to Set'.

Comment: Almost correct: in session tab: "After a session ends:" close. Then in general tab: select default (or other relevant profile) and click button: "copy current settings to selected profile".

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because the session had short life.

Go to **iTerm2 Preferences** -> **Advanced** -> **Warnings** section -> (Last option in the section) **Warn about short-lived sessions that live less than this many seconds.**

The value is configured as **3**, by default. So if you don't need to show broken-pipe for immediately closing sessions, make it as **0**.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you are doing before closing it ? Are you closing it after immediately opening the tab ?

Comment: I didn't do anything when I closed it. After I uninstalled iTerm and reinstalled it again. Then it is no problem.

Comment: The problem occurs when you open and close a tab immediately. In your case, if you open a tab and close it before 3 seconds, it will be thrown.